# Express Error: TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating an upload/download app, i don't know why its only my app.js file is having this problem. I searched all other answers on the internet but still it did not solve the problem.
here is the code below:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');  // add path to set and get
    var fs = require('fs');  // add filesystem
    var connect = require('connect');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var connect = require('connect');
    var http = require('http');
    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    //var upload = require('./routes/upload');
    var app = express();
    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.use(express.static('files'));
    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);
    //app.use('/upload',upload);
    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
    });
    // error handlers
    // development error handler
   // will print stacktrace
   if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: err
   });
   });
   }
   // production error handler
   // no stacktraces leaked to user
   app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
   message: err.message,
   error: {}
   });
   });
   module.exports = app;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you paste the error log?

Comment: throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));
      ^

TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object

Answer (score 0):

check in your all files
make sure you don't miss `export` it

`module.exports = router;`

Comment: They all have export at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

`Router.use()` at all times requires a Middleware function as an argument. Assuming your route to download some files from your server, it should Look similar to this.

```
var Router = express.Router();


function downloadFiles(request,response) {
   // some code to dowload files
}

// The above function which takes request and response
// should be passed to Router.use()

Router.use(downloadFiles);
```

When you that error it means that what you passed to Router.use() is not a middleware function like `downloadFiles`.

Comment: sorry but its not working wither, its still giving me the same errror